# least amount of bits needed for single neuron

Tags: neural-networks

I wonder what is the smallest amount of bits a neuron needs?

For example for speech recognition / image recognition tasks?

Can 4 bits produce as good results as 16 bits, or even 64 bits ?

Is it not a waste to use 16 bits ( or 64 bit double-s)?

For example spin systems can be encoded with only 1 bit per spin and there is a similarity between spins and neurons (Hopfield network).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following papers have studied this question (descending chronological order):

- Accelerating Deep Convolutional Networks using low-precision and sparsity. Ganesh Venkatesh, Eriko Nurvitadhi, Debbie Marr. 2016-10-02. https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.00324
- Binarized Neural Networks: Training Neural Networks with Weights and Activations Constrained to +1 or −1
  Matthieu Courbariaux, Itay Hubara, Daniel Soudry, Ran El-Yaniv, Yoshua Bengio
  arxiv: http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.02830
- Suyog Gupta, Ankur Agrawal, Kailash Gopalakrishnan, Pritish Narayanan
  Deep Learning with Limited Numerical Precision https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.02551
- Courbariaux, Matthieu, Jean-Pierre David, and Yoshua Bengio. "Training deep neural networks with low precision multiplications." arXiv preprint arXiv:1412.7024 (2014). https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7024
- Vanhoucke, Vincent, Andrew Senior, and Mark Z. Mao. "Improving the speed of neural networks on CPUs." (2011). https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14667574137314459294&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/37631.pdf

Example from *Deep Learning with Limited Numerical Precision*:

[image]

---

FYI:

- [FP16 performance on GTX 1080 is artificially limited to 1/64th the FP32 rate (devtalk.nvidia.com)](https://web.archive.org/web/20170301225432/https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/4lhrfj/fp16_performance_on_gtx_1080_is_artificially/?st=iqlpu3i4&sh=0afda9d6)

Comment: These look like some great references, but I'd recommend adding a few words of summary to your answer, even if they're just quotes.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much for your effort summarising the relevant research.